# How can I get the created date of a file on the web (with Python)?

Tags: python, http

I have a python application that relies on a file that is downloaded by a client from a website.

The website is not under my control and has no API to check for a "latest version" of the file.

Is there a simple way to access the file (in python) via a URL and check it's date (or size) without having to download it to the clients machine each time?

**update:** Thanks to those who mentioned the"last-modified" date.  This is the correct parameter to look at.

I guess I didn't state the question well enough.  How do I do this from a python script?  I want to application to check the file and then download it if (last-modified date < current file date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) header.

EDIT: Try [urllib2](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#introduction).

EDIT 2: This [short tutorial](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=122&thread=15024) should give you a pretty good feel for accomplishing your goal.

Comment: Also you may want to consider using the ETag header (in conjunction with sending a If-None-Match header in the request)

Answer (score 8):

There is no reliable way to do this.  For all you know, the file can be created on the fly by the web server and the question "how old is this file" is not meaningful.  The webserver may choose to provide Last-Modified header, but it could tell you whatever it wants.

Answer (score 6):

Take into account that 'last-modified' may not be present:

```
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> f=urlopen('http://google.com/')
>>> i=f.info()
>>> i.keys()
['set-cookie', 'expires', 'server', 'connection', 'cache-control', 'date', 'content-type']
>>> i.getdate('date')
(2009, 1, 10, 16, 17, 8, 0, 1, 0)
>>> i.getheader('date')
'Sat, 10 Jan 2009 16:17:08 GMT'
>>> i.getdate('last-modified')
>>>
```

Now you can compare:

```
if (i.getdate('last-modified') or i.getheader('date')) > current_file_date:
  open('file', 'w').write(f.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTTP 1.1, the [Content-Disposition header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) is intended to hold this kind of information in the `creation-date` parameter (see [RFC 2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt)).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an updated answer here to the question...
I found this code works for an excel file, for example. Pretty sure it is going to depend on what the server decides to make available.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
URL = 'url'
with urlopen(URL) as f:
    print(dict(f.getheaders())['Last-Modified'])
    # Remove the ['Last-Modified'] if you want to see what is in the header
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a tool that does this based on etags.  Sounds a lot like what you're describing:

[pfetch](http://github.com/dustin/pfetch) is a twisted tool that does this on a schedule and can run with many, many URLs and trigger events upon change (post-download).  It's pretty simple, but still might be more complicated than you want.

[This code](http://github.com/dustin/snippets/tree/master/python/net/http/fetch.py) however, is exactly what you're asking for.

So, take your pick.  :)